# React/Redux handling API server errors in reducer to display on UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have created an uploader to upload a CSV file, this gets converted into json and sent to the API.

The API has validation if the data is not valid and it returns a response I can see in my debugger:

```
{"success":false,"errorCode":"880ddb963e40","errorMessage":"There are Ids which do not exist in system"}
```

My UI outputs a generic message that there was an issue as shown below from my reducer:

```
import {
    PUT_UPLOAD_CSV,
    PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_SUCCESS,
    PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_FAILURE
} from 'constants/BulkUploads/ActionTypes';

const INIT_STATE = {
    uploadLoader: false,
    uploadResponse: '',
    uploadError: ''
}

export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PUT_UPLOAD_CSV: {
            return {
                ...state,
                uploadLoader: true,
                uploadResponse: '',
                uploadError: ''
            }
        }
        case PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_SUCCESS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                uploadLoader: false,
                uploadResponse: 'CSV file uploaded successfully',
                uploadError: ''
            }
        }
        case PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_FAILURE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                uploadLoader: false,
                uploadResponse: '',
                uploadError: 'An error occurred uploading CSV file, please check the data and try again.'
            }
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I want my reducers `uploadError` handle to be able to return the APIs errorMessage rather than my default one so that the error is more specific, and/or use the error code as a lookup to display an appropriate message.

If anybody can assist or point me to some documentation.

***UPDATE - adding my actions***

```
import {
    PUT_UPLOAD_CSV,
    PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_SUCCESS,
    PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_FAILURE,
} from 'constants/BulkUploads/ActionTypes';


export const putUploadCSV = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: PUT_UPLOAD_CSV,
        payload
    };
};

export const putUploadCSVSuccess = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_SUCCESS,
        payload
    }
};

export const putUploadCSVFailure = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_FAILURE,
        payload
    };
};
```

My index.js

```
{uploadError ?

{uploadError}
    :
{uploadResponse}
}
```

***SAGA***

```
function* putUploadCSVRequest(params) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(putUploadCSV, params.payload);
        yield put(putUploadCSVSuccess(response));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        yield put(putUploadCSVFailure(error));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only using `action.type` in the given function. You may very well use another key preferably something like `action.data` or `action.payload` to identify the different types of `PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_FAILURE` action and adjust the reducer accordingly.

To give you an exact solution based on your specific scenario, I might need to understand how you are dispatching actions.

**Update:**

Since you are using action creators `putUploadCSVFailure`, you can create the action as

```
putUploadCSVFailure(response.errorMessage)
```

within the catch or response of your HTTP Client (axios? fetch? xhr?)

Now, the payload is the errorMessage, so update reducer as

```
case PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_FAILURE: {
        return {
            ...state,
            uploadLoader: false,
            uploadResponse: '',
            uploadError: action.payload || 'An error occurred uploading CSV file, please check the data and try again.'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Added my saga - still struggling.... does putUploadCSVFailure(response.errorMessage) replace the yeild put(putUploadCSVFailure(error)?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not sure how you're invoking the action, I can give you a hint to help you with your problem.

You can pass the message parameter to the action and then consume it in your reducer.

Action call:

```
this.props.onUploadError({type: PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_FAILURE, errorMessage: jsonData.errorMessage});
```

Reducer case statement modification:

```
case PUT_UPLOAD_CSV_FAILURE: {
    return {
        ...state,
        uploadLoader: false,
        uploadResponse: '',
        uploadError: action.errorMessage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add check that if api sends error then show api error or show custom error. e.g.

```
const customError = 'An error occurred uploading CSV file, please check the data and try again.'
// in the reducer, assuming action.payload has response
uploadError: action.payload.errorMessage || customError
```